# Streaming query results directly to S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, nodejs-stream

I am using an AWS Lambda function to stream the query data directly to S3 using nodejs pipeline API, the mysql dependency to create a read stream and the "s3-streams" dependency to create a write s3 stream.

And it is working fine for small queries, but when I'm querying more than 100k rows its showing me that there are too many connections

> Error: ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections

pseudo-code:

```
await pipeline(connection.query.stream,transformData,writeStreamToS3)
```

Comment: Can you post your code where you create the read/write streams? My first suspicion is that you are not disposing of your instances

Comment: ```const connection = mysql.createConnection(mysqlParams);
  const queryStream = connection.query(query).stream({ highWaterMark: 5 });

return {
    connection,
    queryStream
  };```

This is where I'm creating the read stream

Comment: what is the trigger of your lambda function ?  How many concurrent lambda are running ? the message comes back from mysql telling you that too many TCP connections are open.  That's why AWS Lambda concurrency is a suspect

Comment: @SébastienStormacq I've tried using a concurrency limit of 5 for the lambda and I'm still recieving the same error.

Comment: Each lambda function will open multiple connections to your database.  How is your configuration pool configured ?  How is the DB configured (what's the max number of connections accepted) ?

Comment: DB is configured to have 90 max connections. I've tried creating a connection pool and adding a connection limit of 10 for that pool but it did not resolve the case.